# Array json cant go for my list view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My ListView does not display JSON array `titulo`. I am receiving the following error on Logcat

```
 06-19 14:02:12.750    6497-6518/com.eu.agendamarinhagrande E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

The follwoing is the MainActivity Class

```
   package com.eu.agendamarinhagrande;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.eu.agendamarinhagrande.JSONParser;
import com.eu.agendamarinhagrande.R;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empresaList;


    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_empresas = "http://www.grifin.pt/projectoamg/Conexao.php";

    // JSON Node names


    private static final String TAG_TITULO = "Titulo";


    // products JSONArray
    String resultado = null;

    ListView lista;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Hashmap para el ListView
        empresaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        // Cargar los productos en el Background Thread

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }//fin onCreate


    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Antes de empezar el background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("A carregar eventos. Por favor espere...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * obteniendo todos los productos
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List params = new ArrayList();
            // getting JSON string from URL
          JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_empresas, "GET", params);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", url_all_empresas.toString());
            resultado = sb.toString();
            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG

                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products

                JSONArray arrayJson = new JSONArray(resultado);
                for (int i = 0; i<arrayJson.length();i++){



                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    JSONObject c = arrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
                    String Titulo = c.getString(TAG_TITULO);


                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap map = new HashMap();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_TITULO, Titulo);


                    empresaList.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            empresaList,
                            R.layout.single_post,
                            new String[]{
                                    TAG_TITULO

                            },
                            new int[]{
                                    R.id.single_post_tv_id

                            });
                    // updating listview
                    //setListAdapter(adapter);
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Please help me understand the problem that is causing my JSON not to be displayed on my ListView.

Comment: Todo o conteúdo deste site deve ser em Inglês.

Comment: Now is english :) Sry wrong site

Comment: that `ï»¿` is a BOM. In this case it indicates that you are not using the correct encoding when parsing your json. (the issue is in `JSONParser` class.)

Comment: and this is why my list view cant receive the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. I commented out some code to make it work,

```
public class test extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    // JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empresaList;


    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_empresas = "http://www.grifin.pt/projectoamg/Conexao.php";

    // JSON Node names


    private static final String TAG_TITULO = "Titulo";


    // products JSONArray
    String resultado = null;

    ListView lista;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        // Hashmap para el ListView
        empresaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new Download().execute();
        // Cargar los productos en el Background Thread

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

       // ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
       // actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }//fin onCreate


    public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String out = null;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();

                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);

                HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url_all_empresas);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                out = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return out;
        }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsa = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String str = jsa.getString("Titulo");
                Log.e("TAG", str);

                String s1 = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
                String regex = Pattern.quote("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+");

                str = new String(s1.replaceAll(regex, "").getBytes("ascii"), "ascii");

                list.add(str);
            }

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(test.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

            // updating listview
            //setListAdapter(adapter);
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value you know why this happen? this the error

Comment: Ty alot you resolve my problem . Now i have to link all this events on list view for one activity talking about him can you help me again ?

Comment: Glad i could help. Please accept this answer and post it as anew question.